# Juego del Ahorcado - Java

Tags: java, bucle-for

Tengo un problema con un programa que estoy haciendo, que es acerca de crear un Juego del Ahorcado.
He usado un `for` para que el caracter ingresado sea igual a uno de los caracteres de la palabra (que es elegida aleatoreamente) y un `if` para verificar si es correcto; hasta allí todo bien.

Pero noté que a la hora de de usar un `else`, a la hora de quitar puntos, el programa sigue restando vidas hasta que el usuario pierda el juego sin oportunidad de que ingrese otro caracter.

Mi duda es que si es posible detener ese `for` e `if` una vez que haya encontrado todos los caracteres (o sea si una palabra tiene dos "A" que se se detenga al encontrarlos y no caiga en el `else`).

Gracias de antemano

PD: Estoy trabajando con múltiples clases, con una siendo `abstract`.
Del `abstract` está el método que `quitaVidas`, que es `true` mientras el usuario aún tenga vidas disponibles.

El código en cuestión:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Usuario
 */
public class JuegoAhorcado extends Juego {

    private String palabraR;
    private int posicionR;
    private ArrayList<String> cadenasAdivinar = new ArrayList();
    protected Random seleccionaCadenaAdivinar = new Random();

    public JuegoAhorcado(int vidas) {
        super(vidas);

        cadenasAdivinar.addAll(Arrays.asList("Tiburon", "Emblema", "Emperador",
                "Ahorcado", "Vidriera", "Elefante", "Paralelepipedo", "Romboide", "Washington",
                "Bebestible", "Kiwi", "Experiencia", "Dorado", "Tarot", "Ataraxia", "Descenso",
                "Mascara", "Caballo", "Excalibur", "Quijote"));

        int menor = 1;
        int mayor = 20;

        int resultado = seleccionaCadenaAdivinar.nextInt(mayor - menor) + menor;

        posicionR = resultado;

        palabraR = cadenasAdivinar.get(posicionR);

    }

    @Override
    public void Juega() {
        try {

            reiniciarPartida();

            char[] letras = palabraR.toCharArray();

            System.out.println("");

            System.out.println(palabraR);

            System.out.println("Adiviné la palabra: \n");

            //oculto = oculto.replaceAll("(?s).", "-");
            char[] oculto = new char[letras.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < letras.length; i++) {
                oculto[i] = '-';
            }

            Lectura Teclado = new Lectura();

            while (vidasRestantes() != 0) {

                System.out.println("");

                System.out.println(oculto);

                System.out.println("Ingrese un caracter: ");

                char letra = Teclado.leerCaracter();

                if (letras == oculto) {

                    System.out.println("\nFelicidades, has completado la palabra " + palabraR);

                    System.out.println(actualizarRecord());
                    break;

                }

                for (int i = 0; i <= letras.length - 1; i++) {
                    if (letras[i] == letra) {

                        oculto[i] = letra;

                        System.out.println("");



                    }
                    else {

                        System.out.println("\nCaracter incorrecto, has perdido una vida");

                        if (quitaVidas() == true) {

                            System.out.println("Le quedan " + vidasRestantes() + " vidas");

                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Has perdido el juego, la palabra era: " + palabraR);

                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solamente.. es pensar un poco en tu logica..

Al querer hacer todo junto, es donde estas complicando el juego.

La idea seria:

ir letra por letra
mostrar las que corresponde (tal como haces ahora)
y.. aca la diferencia.. No tener un else.. si no que tener una bandera que diga si encontro la letra o no...

Y al salir.. verificar esa bandera.. y poner el contenido del else ahi...

Entonces.. veamos solo esa parte de tu codigo:

```
bool bandera = false;
for (int i = 0; i <= letras.length - 1; i++) {
    if (letras[i] == letra) {
        oculto[i] = letra;
        System.out.println("");
        bandera = true;
    }
}
if (!bandera) {
    System.out.println("\nCaracter incorrecto, has perdido una vida");
    if (quitaVidas() == true) {
        System.out.println("Le quedan " + vidasRestantes() + " vidas");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Has perdido el juego, la palabra era: " + palabraR);                           
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, sinceramente se me paso por alto algo tan simple, realmente fue la solución.

Comment: recuerda siempre aceptar las respuestas cuando ellas resolvieron tu problema (tenes otra pregunta a la cual no le aceptaste una respuesta). Si tenes dudas de como funciona el sitio, volve a mirar el [tour]. Saludos!